# Process.Start arguments not working

Tags: vb.net, parameters, process.start

I am trying to start a process with two parameters that will run from a cmd prompt window just fine.  The problem comes when I try to launch it via `process.start`.

In the cmd window, it looks like this.

`D:\Projects\MyProg.exe "D:\Projects\MyScript.txt" "D:\Projects\MyInputData.txt"`

When I try to build the arguments in `.NET` it puts double quotes around the entire string and it looks like this.  The program doesn't interpret it as two parameters and just stops.  If I add double quotes around each argument it still misinterprets it.

I know it is the MyProg.exe issue (vendor program that I can't change) but is there a way to send this command so it will work?

```
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "D:\Projects\MyScript.txt D:\Projects\MyInputData.txt"
```

When I add double quotes it sort of works, the program starts but then has a problem and just stops.

```
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = """D:\Projects\MyScript.txt"" ""D:\Projects\MyInputData.txt"""
```

Comment: The last snippet is most correct, it ensures that spaces in the real path names don't cause trouble.  So you are down to "has a problem and just stops", nobody can possibly guess what that could mean when you don't describe the problem and show this little code.

Comment: David Alves, I'd love to give more info but that is what it does.  There is NO info from the process.  I just stops and doesn't tell me why.  Sorry I can't be more descript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what `D:\Projects\MyProg.exe` is doing but following sample is working for. Two variable strings are declared. The two strings indicate two argument parameters I want to use with the executable.

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    '// Set first file parameter to the executable
    Dim sourceFileName As String = "source.txt"
    '// Set second file parameter to the executable
    Dim targetFileName As String = "target.txt"

    '// Create a new ProcessStartInfo
    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo

    '// Specify the location of the binary
    p.FileName = "D:\_working\ConsoleApplication3.exe"

    '// Use these arguments for the process
    p.Arguments = " """ & sourceFileName & """ """ & targetFileName & """ -optionalPara"

    ' Use a hidden window
    'p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

    ' Start the process
    Process.Start(p)

  End Sub
End Class
```

See resulting screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did it work? If an answer has helped you solve your problem accept it please.

Comment: Thanks help-info.de.  It appears to do as you say.